# Android - addView without blocking UI

Tags: android, json

I want to add Views to my `LinearLayout` without blocking the UI.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(RequestMySellingList result)
{

   for (MySellingData data : result.data)
   {
         LinearLayout rowSelling = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_selling_item, null);

         ImageView iv_sellingItemImage = (ImageView) rowSelling.findViewById(R.id.iv_sellingItemImage);

         iv_sellingItemImage.setImageBitmap(data.bitmap);

         // Add rowSelling to the main list holder
         ll_sellingList.addView(rowSelling);
  }
}
```

**Note:** `ll_sellingList` is `LinearLayout` which holds entries

I can't use `onProgressUpdate()` because I am getting a long-long json response, and I must use the `onPostExecute()` method which gets the full json request.

The problem is if the request is very long - addView blocks the UI

Comment: runOnUiThread ? Did you tried this, it will be a little bit better if you use it.

Comment: Why don't you use a listView? You can make it more efficient. BTW postExecute runs on UIThread @Tsunaze

Comment: I don't use a listView because I am using ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

It will block the UI, because `inflater.inflate()` is a heavy operation. Also, `findViewById` is also not a cheap operation. And you call them lots of times in the for loop. So, better move them out of the for loop like this. Try and see if it works faster without blocking the UI.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(RequestMySellingList result)
{

     LinearLayout rowSelling = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_selling_item, null);

     ImageView iv_sellingItemImage = (ImageView) rowSelling.findViewById(R.id.iv_sellingItemImage);

     for (MySellingData data : result.data)
     {
          iv_sellingItemImage.setImageBitmap(data.bitmap);

          // Add rowSelling to the main list holder
          ll_sellingList.addView(rowSelling);
     }
}
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(24345): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: I just wanted to point out why it blocks the UI. I think you should change your approach here. For example use an adapter instead of adding a linear layout for each image. I can help more if you post all of your AsyncTask code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this when working with accordion style layout where each collapsing item hold also a subset of list as that kind of layout is not working well with RecyclerView Viewholder pattern. I used Concurrent as a replacement for Asynctask then on `doInBackground` all Glide fetch for images and `addView()` call was wrapped using `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {//Your Code});` since Glide and adding view requires it to be run on UI thread. The adding of each layout will be seen one by one in the screen but the good thing is no more frame skip from Choreographer.